# Given six people of different heights, how many ways can we order them so no 3 consecutive people are ordered in increasing height

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Principle_of_Inclusion-Exclusion#Four_Set_Example
Here is where I found the problem, go to the four set example section. My question how do they say |A| is 120. I am very new to combinatorics and counting, so I apologize if I my fundamental understanding is just flawed. A is the event where People 1,2,3 are in ordered height, meaning that People 4-6 can be moved around. Since We can only move around 4-6 wouldn't |A| just be 3!? They say that it is  (6 3), how many combinations of 3 items from 6 items. I'm assuming that 3! is for people 4 - 6 and the combination (6 3) for People 1-3. Hope my question made sense.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your header says  "... **no 3 people** are ordered in increasing height.." wheras the AOPS solves for "...no three **consecutive** people are in increasing order of height..." You need to clarify which problem you need to solve.

Comment: @trueblueanil, yes you are right. Typo on my part.

Comment: @sracha3862: So I suppose you already have a satisfactory answer ?

Comment: @trueblueanil yes

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that the people in increasing order of height are *p1,p2,p3,p4,p5 and p6*.

In scenario A, the people standing in first 3 places are in increasing order of height.
But they need not necessarily be *p1, p2 and p3*. so, first we need to pick three people to arrange in increasing height, which we do using (6 3).
This order may be *{p1,p3,p5}* or *{p2,p3,p4}* we just need to choose any three random people and arrange them in only one possible way which is in increasing order of height.
Then we arrange the remaining three people standing in the fourth, fifth and sixth place in 3! ways.

Comment: Wow thank you, I see I wrongfully made the assumption that in event A, the first 3 people must be P1 , P2, and P3. However if changed our definition of A to my wrong assumption, then would the | A | be 3!?

Comment: @sracha3862 yes you are correct, if the first 3 places are occupied by p1, p2, p3 in increasing order of height then we only need to move P4, p5, p6. Then A would be 3!.